# node.js redirection not working to add username

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers

I am working on a Team Treehouse project that builds a dynamic website with Node.js. The user enters in a username into the search field and it displays the user's avatar, number of badges earned and the number of JavaScript points. For some reason when I enter in the user name and click search the page just goes blank. I think there might be something wrong with the 303 redirection in my router.js file. I'm still fairly new to coding so any insight would be very helpful. Here are each of my js files.

/*****app.js file******/

```
var router = require('./router.js');

//Problem: We need a simple way to look at a user's badge count and JavaScript points from a web browser
//Solution: Use Node.js to perform the profile look ups and serve our templates via HTTP

//Create a web server
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  router.home(request, response);
    router.user(request, response);
}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://<workspace-url>');
```

/*****router.js file******/

```js
var Profile = require("./profile.js");
var renderer = require('./renderer');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var commonHeader = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'};

// Handle the HTTP route GET / and POST / i.e. Home
function home(request, response) {
 //if url == "/" && GET
 if (request.url === '/'){
    if (request.method.toLowerCase() === "get") {
      //show search
      console.log(request.url);
      response.writeHead(200, commonHeader);
      renderer.view('header', {}, response);
      renderer.view('search', {}, response);
      renderer.view('footer', {}, response);
      response.end();
    } 
    else {
      //if url == "/" && POST
      
      //get the post data from body
      request.on('data', function(postBody){
        //extract the username  
        var query = querystring.parse(postBody.toString());
        //redirect to /:username
        response.writeHead(303, {'Location': '/' + query.username });
        response.end();
      });
    }
  }
}
  

// Handle the HTTP route for GET /:username i.e. /chalkers
function user(request, response) {
  //if url == "/...."
 var username = request.url.replace('/', '');
 if(user.name.length > 0){
  response.writeHead(200, commonHeader);
    renderer.view('header', {}, response);
  
  //get json from Treehouse
  var studentProfile = new Profile(username);

  //on "end"
  studentProfile.on("end", function(profileJSON){
   //show profile
   
   //Store the values which we need
   var values = {
    avatarUrl: profileJSON.gravatar_url,
    username: profileJSON.profile_name,
    badges: profileJSON.badges.length,
    javascriptPoints: profileJSON.points.JavaScript
   }
   //Simple response
   renderer.view('profile', values, response);
   renderer.view('footer', {}, response);
      response.end();
   
  });
      
  //on "error"
  studentProfile.on("error", function(error){
   //show error
   renderer.view('error', {errorMessage: error.message}, response);
      renderer.view('search', {}, response);
   renderer.view('footer', {}, response);
      response.end();
  });  
 }
}

module.exports.home = home;
module.exports.user = user;
```

/*****profile.js file*******/

```js
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var http = require("http");
var util = require("util");

/**
 * An EventEmitter to get a Treehouse students profile.
 * @param username
 * @constructor
 */
function Profile(username) {

    EventEmitter.call(this);

    profileEmitter = this;

    //Connect to the API URL (http://teamtreehouse.com/username.json)
    var request = http.get("http://teamtreehouse.com/" + username + ".json", function(response) {
        var body = "";

        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            request.abort();
            //Status Code Error
            profileEmitter.emit("error", new Error("There was an error getting the profile for " + username + ". (" + http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode] + ")"));
        }

        //Read the data
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
            profileEmitter.emit("data", chunk);
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            if(response.statusCode === 200) {
                try {
                    //Parse the data
                    var profile = JSON.parse(body);
                    profileEmitter.emit("end", profile);
                } catch (error) {
                    profileEmitter.emit("error", error);
                }
            }
        }).on("error", function(error){
            profileEmitter.emit("error", error);
        });
    });
}

util.inherits( Profile, EventEmitter );

module.exports = Profile;
```

/*****renderer.js file*******/

```js
var fs = require('fs');

function mergeValues(values, content) {
  //Cycle over the keys 
  for(var key in values) {
    //Replace all the {{key}} with the value from the values object
    content = content.replace('{{' + key + '}}', values[key]);
  }
  //return merged content
  return content;
}

function view(templateName, values, response) {
  //Read from the template file
  var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('./views/' + templateName + '.html', {encoding: 'utf8'});
  //Insert values in to the content
  fileContents = mergeValues(values, fileContents);
  //Write out the contents to the response
  response.write(fileContents);
}

module.exports.view = view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Treehouse changed from http to https and so this example code doesn't work any longer. The reason for that is in the profile.js file. You are making calls for an http site and it doesn't exist. You need to change the code (only in profile.js) to make it connect to the https site instead.

```
var http = require("http");
```

should be changed to

```
var https = require("https");
```

and with that all references to the variable in your profile.js code should be changed to https.

As well as the hard-coded URL start:

```
var request = http.get("http://teamtreehous...
```

should be

```
var request = https.get("https://teamtreehous...
```

That should resolve the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your code in the profile.js file to run, you need to change some instances of the "http" module to "https" but, and this is important, *not all* instances.

What needs to remain http is the the status code error on the profile.js page. This line of code is correct:

```
profileEmitter.emit("error", new Error("There was an error getting the profile for " + username + ". (" + http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode] + ")"));
```

But all other instances of the http module need to change to https. For example, these lines are correct:

```
var url = "https://teamtreehouse.com/" + username + ".json";

var request = https.get(url, function(response){
```

Remember to require both modules at the top of profile.js page

```
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");
```